# Conditional probability of two uniform distributions

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim R(0,1)$ and $Y\sim R(0,1)$, be two independent variables. Calculate: $P(X+Y>1|Y>1/2)$.

I have tried the following:

$$P(X+Y>1\mid Y>1/2)=\frac{P(X+Y>1, Y>1/2)}{P(Y>1/2)}$$

The denominator I can calculate to $1/2$:

$$P(Y>1/2)=1-P(Y\leq 1/2)=1-\int_0^{1/2}1\;dx=1/2$$

And I am currently stuck calculating the numerator. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with densities $f_X$ resp. $f_Y$ the the following holds
$$
\mathbb P (X+Y > a, Y>b) = \int_b^\infty \mathbb P(X>a-y)\cdot f_Y(y)\; dy.
$$
This can be obtained by conditioning on all possible outcomes of $Y$.

In your case we get that
$$
\mathbb P (X+Y > 1, Y>\frac12) = \int_{\frac 12}^1 \mathbb P(X>1-y)\cdot 1\; dy=\int_{\frac 12}^1y \; dy = \frac 12 - \frac 18=\frac 38.
$$